# cross correlation

Tags: matlab

i have been trying to find the cross correlation between a time shifted signal response and another signal response taken as a reference but finding it difficult to make my time shift reflect with the xcorr function. the matlab code is pasted below, i will appreciate if anybody can make a suggestion on how to implement the xcorr function such that i can determine the time shift at which the two signal response correlate. thank you

```
clear all;
clc;
FS = 100e6;



figure(1)
AMP8 = importdata('av250nu.txt');
time8  = [1:length(AMP8)] / FS;
c=find(time8==0.14e-4);
plot(time8(1:c)',AMP8(1:c));
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(2)
AMP = importdata('3kknu.txt');
time  = [1:length(AMP)] / FS;
c=find(time==0.14e-4);
plot(time(1:c)',AMP(1:c));
title('reference')
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(3)
AMP1 = zeros(2000,1);
time1 = zeros(2000,1);
time11 = zeros(2000,1);
AMP1(1:320)= AMP(1:320);
time1(1:320) = time(1:320);
plot(time1,AMP1);
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(4)
AMP2 = zeros(2000,1);
time2 = zeros(2000,1);
time21 = zeros(2000,1);
AMP2(321:640) = AMP(321:640);
time2(321:640) = time(321:640);
time21(321:640) = time2(321:640);
plot(time21,AMP2);
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(5)
AMP3 = zeros(2000,1);
time3 = zeros(2000,1);
time31 = zeros(2000,1);
AMP3(641:960) = AMP(641:960);
time3(641:960) = time(641:960);
time31(641:960) = time3(641:960);
plot(time31,AMP3);
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(6)
AMP4 = zeros(2000,1);
time4 = zeros(2000,1);
time41 = zeros(2000,1);
AMP4(961:1280) = AMP(961:1280);
time4(961:1280) = time(961:1280);
time41(961:2000) = time4(961:2000);
plot(time41,AMP4);
ylabel('Amplitude(V)')
xlabel('Time of flight(s)')

figure(75)
time5=zeros(2000,1);
p = zeros(2000,1);
time5(1:320)= time1(1:320); 
time5(321:640)=time21(321:640);
time5(641:960)=time31(641:960);
time5(961:2000)=time41(961:2000);

plot(time5,AMP);

 p(1:2000) = time5;
 p(1:16384) = AMP;
 plot(p);
 grid on;



 figure(95)
 [Z,lags] = XCORR(p(1:16384,1),AMP8,'biased');
 plot(lags,Z);
```

Comment: thats a lot of code for a simple question

Answer (score 1):

Try to find maximum value of correlation, it is the desired shift.

```
[zmax, i] = max(Z);
t = lags[i];
```

Comment: thanks, the issue am having with the code is that the time shift doesnt reflect in the cross correlated response. every bit of the code comes out fine except the xcorr function. can anyone help with a suggestion on how to write the cross correlation function for the two signals. thank you