# Calculation of cross correlation of time shifted signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

There are 2 signals A(t), B(t) representing output power. A is a time delayed output. How to implement this formula

```
 Cross_cor(delay)=[A(t + delay) − <A(t)>]*[B(t) − <B(t)>] / {[A(t)-<A(t)]^2 * [B(t)-<B(t)]^2} ^2
```

1. I do not understand what the numerator implies?
2. How to plot a color map or something like the surf plot whereby the different regions can be seen with different colors.
3. How to obtain a plot of the cross correlation as a function of the delay shift time (delay X axis, Cross_corr on Y axis) so that the peak can be visualized?

Comment: what did you try do to? why do you think this is a 3-D signal you have? it is only a 1-D signal that you need to plot (delay is the only thing that changes). have you tried to do 'doc xcorr' ?

Comment: I am aware of xcorr built in function. But would this function only give correlation between A,B whereas I want to observe (a) Correlation as a function of delay (b) such that the peak indicates that a strong correlation exists. How do I incorporate the delay parameter into xcorr?About the 3D thing,there are several parameters which influence the correlation. Say, plot of mean correlation dimension vs delay vs the noise.

Comment: Take a look to the "Time series analysis" entry in this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation . The cross-correlation is usually used with data that is stationary from a statistic point of a view. If you apply the cross correlation to stationary signals (with correlated noise), the cross-correlation depends only on the delay term of the equation. In this case you obtain a 2D plot, delay vs cross-correlation.
I have never worked with signals that are not stationary. But, if you had to do a 3D plot, I suppose it would be: (x) t, (y) delay (z) cross correlation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485321/cross-correlation  question states a similar problem of finding the cross correlation for a time shifted signal.Is it possible to do something like that using xcorr(actually wanted to avoid built in function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna say [X] is the mean of X then:

> R(dt) = [(A(t + dt) - [A(t)]) * (B(t) - [B(t)])]/(std(A) * std(B))

The numerator is taking two functions A(t) and B(t) and centering them, this is what subtracting the mean does.  I can create two new functions that make this all look a little bit easier:

> C(t) = A(t) - [A(t)]
>   D(t) = B(t) - [B(t)]

then:

> R(dt) = [C(t + dt) * D(t)]/(std(C) * std(D))

Now I'm muliplying these two functions and taking the mean.  If these two functions are moving exactly with one another this is going to be 1 which mean positive correlation.

You can do this in Matlab by doing the following:

```
a = randn(1,50);
b = randn(1,50);

x1 = mean((a - mean(a)) .* (b - mean(b)))/(std(a) * std(b))
```

This give me the crosscor at dt = 0, for another dt do:

```
x2 = mean((a(2:50) - mean(a(2:50))) .* (b(1:49) - mean(b(1:49))))/(std(a) * std(b))
```